# Cached css/javascript files on Sun Java System Web Server

Tags: web-server, sun-one

I'm doing front-end web development in a Solaris 10 / Sun Java System Web Server 7.0U2 environment. I have noticed that changes to static css or javascript files often do not take effect immediately, whereas changes to static html files always do. My best guess is that a default setting in the web server causes it to cache certain file types in order to provide reasonable performance out of the box. I don't have the admin server running--I'll need to edit the config files by hand. What change(s) can I make so that all of my css and javascript edits take effect immediately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution to my problem was to add nocache="" beneath the appropriate Service directive in obj.conf.

```
Service method="(GET|HEAD|POST)" type="*~magnus-internal/*" fn="send-file"
nocache=""
```

Placing the directive elsewhere in the file resulted in an error when starting the server.

This document was helpful: [Tuning Sun ONE Web Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19199-01/817-1836-10/perftune.html#wp17184)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct caching is enabled by default. To disable it using the command-line-interface, use wadm set-file-cache-prop and set the enabled property to false.